Sparkline and progress bar
I am trying to create a progress bar based on the number of checkboxes checked:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MBw_W6kA2qNQaW5t1WZGuOMYpQkYlCkyTlDZ0yLCrdU/edit?usp=sharing
I have managed to create a bar but I would like to change color, that is based on all checkboxes and not only on the ones on the first column and that it shows a percentage on top of it.
I have tried this formula but it doesn't work:
=SPARKLINE(COUNTIF(B5:B24;E5:E24;H5:H24;K5:K24;TRUE);{"charttype"\"bar";"color"\"#dac4b1";"max"\80})
Could you please help?
Thanks

Exact copy of Sparkline and progress bar. See Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites.


Only change done is stack the ranges in braces {}:
=SPARKLINE(COUNTIF({B5:B24;E5:E24;H5:H24;K5:K24};TRUE);{"charttype"\"bar";"color"\"#dac4b1";"max"\80})



Thanks! This works:
{B5:B24;E5:E24;H5:H24;K5:K24};TRUE)
But I cannot change the color, no matter what code I enter, it stays orange.

Change color to color1
